# Pass data from ViewController to TableViewController using segue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have created a Calculator using Swift in Xcode. I would like to add another functionality to it, I already have a history label that displays the previous calculations. I would like to pass the data that displays in that history label into a TableViewController and for each calculation my history label shows to have it add each data into my TableViewController. I know I should be able to use perform segue, but I'm not exactly sure. Here is my code so far:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var HistoryLabel: UILabel!

    var userIsTypingNumbers = false

    @IBAction private func NumbersEntered(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //know what number is being pressed
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        //if user is typing a number, do this.
        if userIsTypingNumbers{
            //specify what number is being pressed
            let textCurrentDisplay = displayLabel.text!
            //append the another number onto the previous number.
            displayLabel.text = textCurrentDisplay + digit
        } else {
            displayLabel.text = digit
        }
        userIsTypingNumbers = true
    }
    var displayValue: Double {

        get {
            return Double(displayLabel.text!)!
        }
        set {
            displayLabel.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }

    private var calculations = PerformCalculations()

    @IBAction func Enter(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //perform the calculations
        if userIsTypingNumbers{
            calculations.setOperand(operand: displayValue)
            userIsTypingNumbers = false
        }
        if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
            calculations.performOperation(symbol: mathematicalSymbol)
        }
        HistoryLabel.text = HistoryLabel.text! + String(sender.currentTitle!);displayValue = calculations.result
        HistoryLabel.text = HistoryLabel.text! + String(displayValue)

    }


    @IBAction func Clear(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //clear display to 0.
        displayLabel.text = "0"
        HistoryLabel.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func Delete(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //deleting last typed number, if user messed up.
        let name: String = self.displayLabel.text!
        //count number of characters.
        let stringLength = name.characters.count
        let substringIndex = stringLength - 1
        displayLabel.text = (name as NSString).substring(to: substringIndex)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "History"){
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? HistoryClassViewController{
                destinationVC
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have started attempting a prepare for segue function, but not sure how to make it work. Any help would be much appreciated. Hopefully this makes sense. Here is a picture of how my Calculator is laid out in Xcode:

[image: Calculator Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create in your `HistoryClassViewController` field like

```
var someData: Any!
```

Then:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "History" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as! HistoryClassViewController {
            destinationVC.someData = something
        }
    }
}
```

Then to perform segue in place you wants to type this:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "History", sender: self)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes very helpful, Thank You!

Comment: @walkerofskies1 glad to hear it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is thing Take one **String Variable** as **global Variable** in **HistoryClassViewController class**

example:

```
class HistoryClassViewController: UITableViewController{
    var dataString:String!

    //............Continue code
    //............
```

Now Write this Method in ViewController class

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if (segue.identifier == "History"){
                if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? HistoryClassViewController{
                    destinationVC.dataString = displayLabel.text!
                }
            }

    }
```

Finally access dataString value in TableViewController.